# Crystal report parameter having datatype date or date time not visible in Select expert

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In crystal report when i make a parameter with type date or date time first it give a warning "A string is required here" .And when i change its type to string then it show a blank report .

While in data set it give record in table .But when it is assign to report data source it show blank report.

Comment: What is the datatype in the database for the date or datetime value?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your Date field in Query is also in Date or datetime format.

```
select * from TableName
Where Cast(DateField as Date) between Cast('?StartDate' as date) and Cast('?EndDate' as date)
```